# Fail to connect to Rethink DB through nodejs

Tags: node.js, database, rethinkdb

I am facing an issue while trying out RethinkDB, and i am unable to find the answer at the moment. So hopefully one of you can help me out here.

I am trying to make a connection to the database with the following code.

```
r = require('rethinkdb');

var connection = null;
r.connect({ host: 'localhost', port: 28015, db: 'test' }, function(err, conn) {
    // console.log(err);
    if (err) throw err;
    connection = conn;
    console.log(connection);
});
```

While i try to run the node file it is generating the following issue:

**ReqlTimeoutError: Could not connect to localhost:28015, operation timed out.**

The RethinkDB is running, and im able to connect to it through the browser through the 8080 port.

Does anyone knows what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error message, **Could not connect to localhost:28015**, seems to indicate that the server is not available on *localhost* port *28015*.

Check if your server is still running and that the logs say something like this:

```
Listening for client driver connections on port 28015
Listening on driver addresses: 127.0.0.1, ::1
```

Perform a plain TCP connection to make sure the sever is reachable:

```
var net = require('net');
var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(8080, 'localhost', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
});
```